# Joomla https redirect to different domain

Tags: joomla-3.x, redirect, https

I'm using Joomla 3.6.2 and I can't understand how to do a simple thing.
I'm using cloudflare so I can't use the www.example.com url for https, but I need to use https:// example.com

What I want is to simple redirect http:// www.example.com/administrator to https:// example.com/administrator automatically.

Another e-commerce oriented cms allow me to select a specific url for https pages, like without www. I can't understand how to do this with Joomla.

I can't use htaccess redirect because when I write https:// www.example.com the connection is closed by cloudflare.

Thanks

Comment: Opened an issue here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/11574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it is perfectly possible to use a free Cloudflare account for getting https on the www. I've set this up for dozens of domains using a free Cloudflare account. (Unless they have changed their policy recently)

The best way to achieve this is probably to let Cloudflare redirect http and https to your server.
You can do this in your domain's Crypto tab on Cloudflare. At the SSL settings  choose "Full". 
The "Full" settings only work if you have a certificate installed for your hosting account. This can be a self signed certificate or the default certificate for your hosting account.

In the DNS settings of cloudflare you can point the normal A record for the domain name as well as the www A record to your server's ip address. Make sure  and set the status (the cloud with the arrow in the right column) to make use of cloudflare.
In my experience this is perfectly possible with free Cloudflare accounts.

Now that all www, non-www, http and https traffic is going through Cloudflare to your hosting account, make sure that you configure your hosting provider so that http and https are pointed to look to the same folder.

On your server redirect all non-www traffic to the www. domain. If you're using Apache you can use .htaccess for redirection of all non-www to www:

```
##### Redirect non-www to www -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
##### Redirect non-www to www -- END
```

You can redirect all http traffic to https in Joomla's configuration: 
Global Configuration > Server > Force https > Entire site
This can give errors if you haven't set Cloudflare's SSL settings to Full.

You could also do both www and https issues, and even more fine-tuning, with Akeeba Admin Tools Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question - but your issue is purely with cloudfare. If they are blocking `http://www` from even touching the server, then I can't see how any setting in Joomla would help.

Comment: Cloudflare is blocking connections on 443 for www because it's a free account. What I need is to force joomla to use a different domain only for https connections, for example https:// example.com or https:// secure.example.com
So, the administrator will be https:// example.com/administrator. On another CMS for e-commerce the is a simple <input> with this label "use this domain for https connection", and I wrote https:// example.com
I can't do this with Joomla.

Comment: I add another information about the other cms: if I write https:// www.example.com of course it doesn't work. But, for thing like login or cart it automatically switch between http:// www.example.com and https:// example.com